# Dynamic field parse date value with react-hook-form using MUI DatePickers

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form, muipickersutilsprovider

I´m not being able to pass the parsed date to the submit object of react-hook-form. I need to handle the parsing at the field level because this is a dynamic form so I can´t control which fields the user will use.

I´m using "setValue()", and I can see the value being defined when using "watch()" but when submit it gets undefined. Can´t find what I´m doing wrong.

Here is a reproducible example:

[image: Edit lively-sun-cbnem]

Thanks!